# Getting Error on typescript Version 4.7.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

On build and deployement, getting the following error with typescript

/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42530
ts.Debug.assert(typeof typeReferenceDirectiveName === "string", "Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.");
^
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42530:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:623:55
at Array.map ()
at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:622:33)
at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116611:163)
at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116911:26)
at processTypeReferenceDirectives (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118393:31)
at findSourceFileWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118278:21)
at findSourceFile (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118133:26)
at processImportedModules (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118539:25)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Provide more information on where the error is occurring and include full details of the problem so that others can reproduce it themselves. Have a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: On another note, it looks like this might be a bug with TypeScript if you're using just the standard `tsc` and not messing around with the compiler API.